# tensolflowでmnistの学習　データの正規化について

Tags: python, 機械学習, tensorflow, 深層学習

私は詳解ディープラーニングという書籍を使いtensorflowの学習を行っています.

そこで疑問なのですが,データを正規化させて重みにも1/√nをかけて実行したのですが正解率が正規化する前よりも下がってしまいまいした.その理由がわからないので教えていただきたいです.

自分では,重みの初期値の設定の仕方が間違っている可能性があると思っていますが,具体的にどう間違っているのかがわかりません.

なおこの学習で用いたモデルは隠れ層3層
ノード数全て200
活性化関数relu
出力層softmax
誤差関数SGDを用いました.

この実装では正答率はだいたい70~80%でした.
正規化を行わない場合全く同じモデルで94%以上でした.
以下コードです.(正規化を行ったコードです.)

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_mldata
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
mnist = fetch_mldata('MNIST original', data_home = '.')

class DNN(object):
  def __init__(self, n_in, n_hiddens, n_out):
    self.n_in = n_in
    self.n_out = n_out
    self.n_hiddens = n_hiddens
    self.weight = []
    self.bias = []

    self._x = None
    self._y = None
    self._t = None
    self._sess = None
    self._keep_prob = None
    self._history = {
        'loss':[],
        'accuracy':[]
    }



  def weight_variable(self,shape):
    #initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.01)
    initial = np.sqrt(1.0 / shape[0]) * tf.truncated_normal(shape)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

  def bias_variable(self,shape):
    initial = tf.zeros(shape)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

  def inference(self, x, keep_prob):
    for i,n_hidden in enumerate(self.n_hiddens):
      if i == 0:
        input = x
        input_dim = self.n_in

      else:

        input = output
        input_dim = self.n_hiddens[i-1]

      self.weight.append(self.weight_variable([input_dim, n_hidden]))
      self.bias.append(self.bias_variable([n_hidden]))

      h = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(input, self.weight[-1]) + self.bias[-1])
      output = tf.nn.dropout(h, keep_prob)

    self.weight.append(
        self.bias_variable([self.n_hiddens[-1], self.n_out]))
    self.bias.append(self.bias_variable([self.n_out]))

    y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(
    output, self.weight[-1]) + self.bias[-1])

    return y

  def loss(self, y, t):
    cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(t * tf.log(y),axis = 1))
    return cross_entropy

  def training(self,loss):
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
    train_step = optimizer.minimize(loss)
    return train_step

  def accuracy(self,y,t):
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(t, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
    return accuracy

  def fit(self, X_train, Y_train,
          nb_epoch=100, batch_size=100, p_keep=0.5):

    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = [None, self.n_in])
    t = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = [None, self.n_out])
    keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

    self._x = x
    self._t = t
    self._keep_prob = keep_prob


    y = self.inference(x, keep_prob)
    loss = self.loss(y, t)
    train_step = self.training(loss)
    accuracy = self.accuracy(y, t)

    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess = tf.Session()
    sess.run(init)

    self._sess = sess
    self._y = y

    for epoch in range(nb_epoch):
      X_, Y_ = shuffle(X_train,Y_train)

      for i in range(len(X_train) // batch_size):

        start = i * batch_size
        end = start + batch_size

        sess.run(train_step, feed_dict = {
            x:X_[start:end],
            t:Y_[start:end],
            keep_prob:p_keep
        })

      loss_ = loss.eval(session = self._sess, feed_dict = {
          x:X_train,
          t:Y_train,
          keep_prob:1.0
      })

      accuracy_ = accuracy.eval(session = self._sess, feed_dict = {
          x:X_train,
          t:Y_train,
          keep_prob:1.0
      })

      self._history['loss'].append(loss_)
      self._history['accuracy'].append(accuracy_)

      print('epoch:', epoch,
            ' loss:', loss_,
            ' accuracy:', accuracy_)

    return self._history

  def evaluate(self, X_test, Y_test):
    accuracy = self.accuracy(self._y,self._t)
    return accuracy.eval(session = self._sess, feed_dict = {
          self._x:X_test,
          self._t:Y_test,
          self._keep_prob:1.0
      })


if __name__ == '__main__':

  n = len(mnist.data)
  N = 10000  # MNISTの一部を使う
  indices = np.random.permutation(range(n))[:N]  # ランダムにN枚を選択

  X = mnist.data[indices]
  #X = X / X.max()
  #X = X - X.mean(axis = 1).reshape(len(X),1)

  X = X / 255.0
  X = X - X.mean(axis=1).reshape(len(X), 1)

  y = mnist.target[indices]
  Y = np.eye(10)[y.astype(int)]  # 1-of-K 表現に変換

  X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, train_size=0.8)

  '''
  モデル設定
  '''

  model = DNN(n_in=len(X[0]),
              n_hiddens=[200, 200, 200],
              n_out=len(Y[0]))

  '''
  モデル学習
  '''
  model.fit(X_train, Y_train,
            nb_epoch=50,
            batch_size=200,
            p_keep=0.5)

  '''
  予測精度の評価
  '''
  accuracy = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test)
  print('accuracy: ', accuracy)
```

ご教示のほどよろしくお願いいたします.

Comment: 正規化することにより入力される信号の絶対値が小さくなる.重みも小さくなることで,誤差逆伝播するときに勾配が正規化したため小さくなってしまっていることが考えられると思います.そのため学習が進みづらくなってしまっていると考えましたがこの考え方でよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: ノイズを加えたから問題が難しくなったのだと思いました。